# Facebook get invited friends id

Tags: facebook, facebook-invite-friends

I am able to get list of inviteable friends using this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends.
But I am not getting ids of Facebook friends.

Or if it is not possible Can I get list of invited_friends?

I want to show friends as "invited" if user has invited them.

Answer (score 1):

You get an invite token, not the ID of the users. The invite token is only valid for a short time, so you cannot use it to identify users later. There is no way to get a list of invited friends either.

Answer (score 1):

In api v2.x, we cannot fetch the user frienda ids. In previous api version, we could fetch all fb friend ids. Invited friends ids was been saved on app server and filter that out from all friends to show invited icon. But in latest version this solution will not work, as there is no call available to fetch friends ids.